# Strange prefix (/A\) in ABAP call stack

Tags: abap, callstack, sap-hr

Generally I try to make my questions Reproducible.
In this case I couldn't find a way. Please feel free to guide me how to grab more details and I will attach.

In some cases, we are using the ABAP call stack programmatically to get additional info. I.E: logging user calls, accessing variables from lower calls in the stack as a last resort when there is no other proper way to retrieve them.

We have encountered a case, in which weird chars were added as a prefix in the call stack for central programs of `HR` module 'MP9XXX00'(`Module-Pool` generated programs for customer-specific `PA` `infotypes`). The weird chars are `/A\`.
The full string for calling program is `/A\MP9XXX00`.

The code used to get the whole call stack:

```
lt_call = cl_abap_get_call_stack=>format_call_stack_with_struct( cl_abap_get_call_stack=>get_call_stack( ) ).
```

There aren't such programs `/A\MP9XXX00` in `SE80`.

Also, when tried to receive variables from calling program as mentioned, like this:
`ASSIGN |( { ls_call-prog })PSYST| it failes`, it caused dump. And when we looked into `ST22` the stack didn't contain any `/A\MP9XXX00` but just `MP9XXX00` (`ls_call-prog` contained `/A\MP9XXX00`).

As said, we didn't manage to reproduce and debug it. just saw the result.

Where could those chars come from?

**What we thought of**

1. We thought that it might be related to the fact that our customer namespace starts with `/A`, but still, why it's shown up? why just a few times? why just the first two characters? and where did the other `\` come from?
2. We thought that the prefix `/A\` might be temporary added to (those) program names, say while importing related transport requests. And that maybe `A` is for `Active/Activating`. What made us think so is that it happens more in `QA` than in production.

Comment: ``/A\`` are normal characters part of the **internal** data of the call stack (method `GET_CALL_STACK`) and it must be formatted (methods `FORMAT_CALL_STACK` or `FORMAT_CALL_STACK_WITH_STRUCT`) so that it can be used. If ``/A\`` remain after formatting, then check SAP notes or contact SAP support.

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi. Never noticed the unformatted call stack.